# How to achieve redundancy with layer 2 switches only in network?

Tags: networking, redundancy

I am trying to find out way to make network design with only simple un-rooted switches which avoid redundancy!

I use 2 computers & 2 simple switches each switch connect to one pc & between both switch I connect 2 wires for check redundancy. But as simple switches always broadcast all packets to all ports except receivers port. So I can't achieve redundancy.

I try with straight wire & cross wire also between 2 switches.

I got solution that by using layer 3 switch I can achieve redundancy but I want to be sure is there no way to achieve this with the help of layer 2 switches ie simple low cost switches.

Comment: No. That's not how it works... A [Trunking Answer](http://serverfault.com/a/145458/33417) I wrote to another question has some good information about link aggregation, which is what you need. I strongly suspect your L3 solution is needlessly complex.

Comment: You want redundancy for 2 computers with simple, unmanaged L2 switches?  Easy.  Plug them both into 1 switch, then set the unused switch right next to the other one.  When the first one fails replace it with the standby switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you have L2 or L3 switches is not relevant to this discussion. What you need is gear that supports spanning tree.

Unfortunately dumb switches don't support spanning tree, so you are likely going to need to purchase some new equipment.

Comment: Thanks EEAA, as by studying various forums & books i know the answer same as you give but not sure whether it is right or wrong...now i confident about what i know...

Comment: @MandarKhire - if you knew spanning tree was likely the answer, then why didn't you mention that in your question? Give us evidence that you've done your own research and things will go much better for you here. If you'd mentioned spanning tree but were wondering if there were other options that didn't require new equipment, you likely would have spared yourself that downvote.

Comment: @MandarKhire - you're welcome. If you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as "accepted".